# What happened to Loki in the Dark World?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, ending, thor-the-dark-world

In [Thor: The Dark World](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1981115/), Thor, Loki and Jane are in the dark elves world.

Thor is in a fight and Loki saves him by impaling the foe with a blade. The enemy then grabs Loki and stabs him with the blade that's sticking out of his chest.

We see Loki die (or fake his death). Thor mourns for his brother and he and Jane leave leaving Loki on the ground.

Then at the end of the movie Thor is talking to Odin. He tells him he can't be the king of Asgard and leaves. After he leaves Odin turns into Loki revealing that Loki is still alive.

How did he fake his death? Was he actually stabbed and just performed the illusion that he stopped breathing until after Thor left?

Comment: In the first Thor movie, Loki uses his ability to create a very convincing illusion to avoid getting hurt during fights and to distract his enemies. I have not seen the new Thor movie, but maybe he employs a similar strategy.

Comment: Loki used kage-bunshin-no jutsu

Comment: One possibility: Loki did not stab the creature with a big blade, but with a knife, while creating the illusion of a large blade passing through the creatures chest. After all, Loki didn't have a large blade right before the event, only a knife. The goal was not to kill the creature with a blade but to distract the creature from Loki's real goal -- to stick a grenade on its hip. So the creature thought that it stabbed Loki back, which was already an illusion, as the blade was an illusion itself. Thor saw the event the way the creature saw it. After the grenade exploded, Loki faked the rest.

Answer (score 7):

When Loki creates illusions, people pass through them. But in the Avengers, Loki has an illusion of himself and it is touched, yet the hand didnt go through. He obviously became stronger so he can create illusions that can still be touched. After all, he created the illusion in his cell, and the one where he it looked like he cut Thor's hand.

Loki created an illusion of himself. Either that or he WAS stabbed, but had the power to heal himself.

Answer (score 6):

It's either Loki faked it by illusions or:

1. When the convergence happened (alignment of realms) he escaped hel or valhalla and returned his soul to his body, or
2. Because of his Jotenhium heritage but living in Asgard, maybe there was a genetic mutation in his body.

Also how did he obtain the Throne? We know that guard was actually him, when he told Odin, Loki died.

Answer (score 4):

Loki is the god of tricks, yes he faked his death. When Odin sent his Asgardian guard to look for Thor, Loki had killed the guard and flew back to Asgard and continued his identity as the guard to report the death of himself to Odin. Odin must have been killed or something leaving Loki to morph his identity as Odin in the scene with Thor later.

Comment: Odin may just not be in the throne room at that time and gone to deal with something else. He doesn't die until Thor: Ragnarok.

Answer (score 2):

Remember how Loki use illusions to trick Malekith that he cut Thor's hand. I think he did the same trick to fake his own death

Answer (score 1):

So as you know Loki is alive after everyone watched him die. The reasoning for this is because Loki's death was a clever illusion made to deceive Thor and Jane so he would be given a legacy as a hero and be seen differently by the people. He then creates an illusion to disguise himself as his father Odin and is basically the King of Asgard as he has always wanted. This just leaves the question, "what happened to Odin?" In Thor Ragnarok: Thor suspects that Loki is still alive once there are enemies such as Surtur, plan on destroying Asgard and he is just sitting around, eating grapes, and watching plays that idolize Loki. Loki confesses that he  sin't really dead, he has been pretending to be Odin, and claims to have left Odin in front of a building being destroyed, which Odin is enjoying a view before he perishes and dies, reuniting the brothers to fight Hela (The Goddess of Death).